# LocalStorage not being cleared on app uninstall - Android 6

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

i'm having a problem where the localstorage doesn't get cleared when i uninstall the app (ionic app). It's only happening on my Samsung S7 Edge with Android 6 (at least is the only device with Android 6 that i have).

The only way of clearing it is by Clearing Data/Cache through the Application Manager of the device...

It works properly on other devices... Since the localstorage implementation is pretty straightforward I have no clue why this is happenning...

Any ideas?

Comment: if you uninstall the app, does it still exist in Application manager? coz if it does it's not yet uninstalled it's just probably the shortcut to your app

Comment: I've had situations where I uninstalled an app from the device but it was still there in the phone's app settings page; just removed from the app drawer.

Try uninstalling the app from the adb command `adb uninstall com.package.name`

Comment: Hi boys, the application is fully uninstalled from app manager, and i uninstalled through app manager and through adb. LocalStorage is still there after reinstallation...

Comment: So @ale.m have you found a solution to that?? Same problem i have on LG G4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Android 6 has automatic backup on.

Did you try setting **android:allowBackup="false"** and **android:fullBackupContent="false"** in your manifest.xml?

**android:allowBackup** and **android:fullBackupContent** are properties of `<application/>` in application's manifest.xml.

In ionic 2, you can find this under platforms folder also.
You can use these properties in case, if you don't want your data backed up or if you want to include or exclude some resources.

I also struggled with it for a long time on Lenovo Vibe phone. This solved it.

Comment: Where exactly is this added in the AndroidManifest.xml?  I added this to both the `<application />` and the `<manifest />` sections and then when I recompiled my cordova/ionic app the XML was overwritten and removed the above lines.  The only time I got my LG phone to completely remove the data was to put the phone in airplane mode and compile the app to my phone - seems Google is feeding my app backed up files each time it loads or reinstalls from scratch.

Comment: In ionic 2 app, there is a folder named platforms. There you will see folders for the platforms that you added. In android folder, you will see a file named `AndroidManifest.xml`. Where `<application>` will be already present. You have to add these 2 properties there. E.g. this is what I have in my `AndroidManifest.xml` :- `<application android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupContent="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">`.

Comment: Kulkami - see my answer below

Comment: Definitely after the app install. Not sure about if we clear the data manually from the settings. You can check about it. I think it should also clear the data.

Comment: How can we achieve the same in PWA ??

Answer (score 3):

I had problems adding those lines to my AndroidManifest.xml in my cordova /progject/platforms/android folder - each time I did it was overwritten every time I compiled the app.  I had to add the following to my /project/config.xml file in order to get the manifest edits to take:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml"
             target="/manifest/application"
             mode="merge">
    <application android:allowBackup="false"/>
    <application android:fullBackupContent="false"/>
</edit-config>
```

Comment: Please tell where I've to place this code? I mean under which tag ?

Comment: @atishr - I believe it goes within the <platform name="android"> tag...if not, then it goes at the same level as the platform tag.

Comment: another doubt. If i set android:allowBackup="false" and android:fullBackupContent="false" when my localStorage data will get flush