# Can I use localStorage to create a permanent database?

Tags: javascript, android, html, local-storage, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm currently learning about hybrid app development on my own. I need to create a local database on the phone in order to save some information, however, I don't know much about storage.

I've seen HTML5 Local Storage (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), and it's easy and confortable to apply, but I don't know if this kind of storage will be permanent on a hybrid app when the phone turns off or when the app closes.

Can you, please, help me with this doubt?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of what kind of information do you want to save.

If you need to save some app information (color, kind of font...) it's ok. But if you want to save some personal information (credit card, id) is better if you use a some database.

You just need to be aware the information that is in localStorage will be deleted for the user anytime so ask yourself, does it matter if all the information is deleted?

Comment: The information to save, that I have in mind, is not that important. Will not mind to me if it's deleted for the user.
The only thing I need to know is: the information will be delete if the user close the app? the information will be delete if the user uninstall the app?
Thanks for your answer and your time, Arnold!

Comment: Don't worry about the information it will stay if the app is closed, to be sure I research about your second answerd and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596270/localstorage-not-being-cleared-on-app-uninstall-android-6) I hope it helps you

Answer (score 3):

Local storage isn't permanent, the user can clear the data whenever they wish. This means it stays until they choose to clear the data, a reboot won't affect it. If you really need to store data permanently, why not create your own server, or integrate with a cloud-based storage service (e.g. Google Drive) so you can store user data there?

Comment: Thanks, but I would like users to be able to save information even if they're offline; so cloud-based storages won't serve for me.
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I recently started using [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/). I find it very useful and pretty easy to use. It's a local database that persists until you uninstall the app.

Comment: Thank you, MacLean, I'm going to take a look at Realm!